# understanding spark.default.parallelism in local mode

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

Hi just for my understanding on the spark.default.parallelism parameter

Given that documentation :

> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

I see that this variable should be the number of cores in my machine. 
So i have 4 cores :

```
nproc
4
```

But this :

```
 println("TEST---> " + sparkSession.sparkContext.defaultParallelism )
```

This this command :

```
spark-submit \
  --class PartitioningTest \
  --master local \
  --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=application.properties" \
  --driver-class-path $JARFILE \
  $JARFILE
```

prints out

> TEST---> 1

As the doc says i was expecting 4

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*--master local* runs Spark with one thread, you should use local[*] to use all your cores.